# TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import '../Search.css';
import React, {setState} from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import PrepodsList from './PrepodsList';
import prepods from "../Data";

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />

const Search = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = setState('');
    const filteredNames = prepods.filter(prepod => {
        return prepod.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    })
    

    return(
        <div className="search">
            <div className="input-container">
                <input placeholder="Name" type="text" onChange ={(event) => setState(event.target.value)}></input>
                <button onClick={this.addSearch}>{element}</button>
            </div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {filteredNames.map(prepod => (
                <PrepodsList name={prepod.name} key={prepod.id} faculty={prepod.faculty} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

This is my Component!

I do not know how to fix this problem.
I don't understand why I don't have my list filtered.
I read a lot of information but still can't solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqYZB.png)

Comment: Well explain what should happen here= `const [value, setValue] = setState('');` You are trying to do what? beacuse this is not how you set values of array items.

Comment: Did you mean to write `useState` in place of `setState`? Please go through the official hooks tutorial for a better understanding: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @xyres I don't think that a typo; he imports `setState` also.

Comment: Yes. Thank You! I understood this my mistake.

Comment: @codemonkey There's no `setState` export in react (you can verify this in [source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js)). No errors are thrown for bad imports at runtime, so you can `import { anything }` without errors. Webpack will only throw an error during compile time.

Comment: @xyres I wasn't arguing that there is a `setState` export in react. I only wanted to point out that he MEANT to use `setState` (incorrectly) because he even imported it (incorrectly). So it wasn't a typo, but a deliberate act on his part.